# When will the capacity of a vector reduce?

Tags: c++, stl

(This question is not about the `shrink_to_fit` tricks (using `swap()` or `shrink_to_fit()` in C++11).)

If I use a vector only through `insert()`, `erase()`, `push_back()`, `pop_back()`, `clear()`, when the capacity is not enough, it will increase and reallocation for the vector will occur. But under what circumstances will the capacity reduce? And will capacity reduction necessarily cause reallocation?

Answer (score 9):

The standard guarantees that no references/iterators will be invalidated during e.g. `pop_back`.  From [container.requirements.general]:

> Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a
>   container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate
>   iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.

And there is no specification otherwise for e.g. `pop_back`.

So that implies that reallocation cannot occur.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub>1. It has been suggested in comments to another answer that perhaps the memory corresponding to a popped element could be freed, which wouldn't invalidate any references to "live" elements.</sub>

But then that would prevent the array from regrowing, as the standard specifically says that insertions cannot provoke a reallocation until the size exceeds the capacity.  From [vector.capacity]:

> It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after
>   a call to `reserve()` until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than
>   the value of `capacity()`.

Comment: What's the conclusion, then? It seems that these sum to that the capacity will never reduce, considering the memory of a vector is contiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, `pop_back()` doesn't do it. Others certainly don't. The only way is the way you mentioned.

```
template< typename T, class Allocator >
void shrink_capacity(std::vector<T,Allocator>& v)
{
   std::vector<T,Allocator>(v.begin(),v.end()).swap(v);
}
```

And `shrink_to_fit()` in c++11

Comment: And that C++03 solution indeed causes a reallocation plus associated copies. (C++11 should use moves).

Answer (score 0):

It **could** be reduced when usage is below 1/4 of capacity (this will give amortized constant cost of reallocation). But STL implementation is not obligated to reduce vector anytime, when you use only methods you have listed.

Comment: The standard guarantees that no references/iterators will be invalidated during e.g. `pop_back`.  So that implies that reallocation cannot occur.

Comment: For vector capacity (allocated memory) and reserved space (the actual number of elements) are two different things. You can not have reliable iterator to element at index above reserved space. And you could free its memory.
Anyway reallocation happens, when vector grows.

Comment: @Greg : No, because `std::vector<>`'s memory is guaranteed to be contiguous -- you can't reallocate (or shrink) some portion without reallocating the entire buffer.

Comment: @Greg: Vector capacity **is** the reserved space.  You may be thinking of vector size.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Your argument indicates that reallocation cannot occur, but the memory allocated at the end of the vector could be freed, which would not invalidate iterators pointing at the beginning.

Comment: @LucTouraille, C++ doesn't give any standard mechanism for releasing part of an allocation - it's all or nothing.

Comment: @Luc : How could one free memory at the end while keeping memory at the beginning, given that all memory must be contiguous?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, why don't you propose that as an answer? It'd get an upvote from me.

Comment: @ildjarn: That's what I am writing about. Vector might be reallocated on `push_backs()`. so the same applies to shrining.

Comment: @Greg : No, the standard specifically permits reference/iterator invalidation during `push_back()`, but _not_ during `pop_back()` or `erase()` (except for the directly-affected elements and those that follow, of course).

Comment: @LucTouraille: if the `Allocator` interface had some kind of "reallocate" operation, then maybe vectors could reallocate downwards without invalidating references. But it doesn't, so they can't.

Comment: @Mark: Doh, you are right, of course! For a moment, I thought about doing something along the lines of `delete[] &buffer[size]`, which is obviously wrong! Sorry for the stupid comment...

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard doesn't need `std::vector` to reduce the `capacity()` at any point of time during its existence. This is strictly implementation dependent So Implementations might on their own but you shouldn't rely on that behavior.

Comment: I don't think it's implementation dependent -- I'm pretty sure it's not allowed. If, for example, if you have 1000 items in a vector, clear it, then push_back 1000 more items, the latter *can't* invalidate any iterators, so it can't involve any reallocation.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Do you mean standard does not allow to reduce capacity?

Comment: I guess technically it could reduce capacity without reallocating, but that would seem a bit pointless.

Comment: C++2003 23.2.4.2/5 "It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after a call to
reserve() until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the size
specified in the most recent call to reserve()."

Comment: @JerryCoffin: why don't you propose a correct answer to OP's question?

Comment: @JerryCoffin `clear()` invalidates all iterators, references, and pointers to elements of a sequence container. [sequence.reqmts] 23.2.3 Table 100

Comment: @bames53: Yes, the clear invalidates all existing iterators/reference/pointers. What I'm talking about, however, is while you're inserting 1000 elements again. You insert 1000 elemnts, `clear()`, then insert one element, get its iterator, then insert 999 more -- that iterator you obtained to the first inserted element must remain valid (because capacity was previously >=1000, and has never been reduced).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I guess I don't see where that requirement is in the spec. If `clear()` does reduce the capacity (taking advantage of the fact that all the iterators are invalidated anyway) then `insert()` will be allowed to invalidate iterators as it allocates more space. So what is it that says that if the capacity was at 1000 at some point in the past it can't be reduced?

Comment: @bames53: What says it could? `clear` invalidates iterators, but that does not give it permission to reduce the capacity.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If reducing the capacity doesn't violate any requirements imposed by the standard then a conforming implementation may do it. It's entirely possible that I'm missing some requirement like 'unless otherwise specified no sequence container member function shall modify the value returned by capacity()`, but I haven't found anything like that yet.

Comment: @bames53: I'm not aware of a direct statement to that effect, but (at the very least) you'd have to jump through a lot of hoops to make it work. For example, `reserve`: "It is guaranteed that no reallocation takes place during insertions that happen after
a call to reserve() until the time when an insertion would make the size of the vector greater than the value of capacity()."  To meet this, you'd have to track whether the previous capacity came about from `push_back` or `reserve`, and reduce the allocation during `clear`/`erase` *only* in the former case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm not sure that statement about reserve() restricts clear() from reallocating. It specifies the value of capacity() as the relevant limit, not necessarily the value passed to reserve(). Consider: `vector<int> v; v.reserve(9); v.swap(vector<int>()); v.push_back(1);` swap is defined to swap capacity values, so push_back may increase capacity and cause reallocation despite the fact that space was reserved. clear() isn't required to modify the value returned by capacity, but I don't think that requirement on reserve restricts it from doing so any more than it restricts swap().

Comment: @bames53: I think it does. It seems clear (no pun intended) to me that `reserve(100); clear(); for (int i=0; i<100; i++) push_back();` can't involve any reallocation.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Okay. I'm not persuaded but I'm content to leave it at that : )